# How to redirect multiple old domains to new domain page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

In my .htaccess file I have the below code. If I had to redirect all these domains to a single page on a new domain is there a short-hand way to write the redirect?

www.olddomain.com, olddomain.com
www.olddomain2.com, olddomain2.com
www.olddomain3.com, olddomain3.com

Do I need to keep redeclaring the **RewriteEngine On** statement?

Finally, for the new domain url, how do you specify either http,https? Does the ^ handle anything before the domain name as a wild card, '**^newdomain.com**'

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# REDIRECTS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/some-page-url/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: You ask multiple questions at once, please don't. Ask questions separately.

Comment: About how the patterns in a rewriting rule work and other aspects concerning apache's rewriting module: please consult the _excellent_ documentation. It answers all your questions and comes with great examples.